# SQL Server AS: Set ImpersonationMode via PS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, powershell

Try to create a database in SQL Server Analysis Server (SQLAS, SSAS) version 2012 SP2 if that matters and set Impersonation Mode via Powershell. (try to avoid XMLA script).

Here are my attempts. Does anybody have the right command handy?

Simple create

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")
$DBASserver = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$DBASserver.connect("mysqldbserver.dom.com")

$database=$DBASserver.databases
$database|select-object name, id

$DBASserver.databases.add("Finance")

$db = $DBASserver.databases.item("Finance")
$db.update()
$db.description = "Finance Department Data Mart"
$db.update()
```

Getting info on the current mode: (works)

```
$db = $DBASserver.databases.item("Finance")
$dbmode = $db.DataSourceImpersonationInfo
$dbmode
```

Update: Setting the mode by getting it from another db works. But creating the Mode object new doesn't 
Here working by reading mode from another DB

```
$db1 = $DBASserver.databases.item("MyDBManualSet")
$db2 = $DBASserver.databases.item("MyNewPSDB")
$dbmode = $db1.DataSourceImpersonationInfo
$dbmode
$db2.DataSourceImpersonationInfo = $dbmode
$db2.update()
```

Here my attempts to set the mode `ImpersonationMode` to `ImpersonateServiceAccount` (nothing works)

```
$newMode.ImpersonationInfo = new ImpersonationInfo(ImpersonationMode.ImpersonateServiceAccount)
$db2.DataSourceImpersonationInfo = $newMode
```

or

```
$newMode= new ImpersonationInfo(ImpersonationMode.ImpersonateServiceAccount)
$db2.DataSourceImpersonationInfo = $newMode
```

here the documentation I can't piece together  [MSDN SQL documentation info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.impersonationinfo%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: btw thanks to Muthusamy Anantha Kumar aka The MAK from http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3818381/Script-a-cube-using-Windows-PowerShell-and-AMO.htm to get me started on PS for MS AS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working:

```
$ImpInfo=New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ImpersonationInfo
$ImpInfo.ImpersonationMode = 'ImpersonateServiceAccount'

$db.DataSourceImpersonationInfo = $ImpInfo
$db.update()
```

here a full working PowerShell (PS) example

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices")
$DBASserver = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$DBASserver.connect("mysqldbserver.dom.com")

$database=$DBASserver.databases
$database|select-object name, id

$DBASserver.databases.add("Finance5")

$db = $DBASserver.databases.item("Finance5")
$db.update()
$db.description = "Finance Test 5"
$db.update()

$db = $DBASserver.databases.item("Finance5")
$dbmode = $db.DataSourceImpersonationInfo
$dbmode #This doesn't post info, maybe a refresh issue. 

$ImpInfo=New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ImpersonationInfo
$ImpInfo.ImpersonationMode = 'ImpersonateServiceAccount'

$db.DataSourceImpersonationInfo = $ImpInfo
$db.update()
$db.description = "Finance Test 5 now changed ImpersonationInfo"
$db.update()
$dbmode = $db.DataSourceImpersonationInfo
$dbmode
```